# cypher query to find paths between set of nodes takes a very long time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph where multiple (more than 300) paths can exist between two nodes.

I want to find paths between a particular node and set of nodes. I'm using following query to accomplish this.

// 2,153 and 485 are nodeid.

```
START startnode=node(2), group = node(153 ,485)
MATCH p=startnode-[:C0038969primrel*1..4]->group
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

- C0038969primrel is a specific relationship type. I want to traverse nodes connected with only particular relationship type.

If I change the depth from 1..4 to 1..3 then it returns the result but for 1..4 it doesn't return.

- I'm using embedded database. Should I have my database on server and increase maxmemory? would that help?
- Should I have different kind of query to accomplish the same?

I'm kind of stuck because of this. Would really appreciate, moreover, grateful for your help.

Comment: more memory would certainly help, how much heap do you have right now? I assume it runs into GC issues.

Comment: Hi michael, 
allShortestPaths seems to be handling this issue.
I'm using embedded database and the java program gets 2 gigs of heap.
should I use neo4j server and rest api for querying or embedded database would be better option? I saw discussion about both on some threads but for this kind of queries which one should be better option?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `shortestPath` or `allShortestPaths`

```
START startnode=node(2), group = node(153 ,485)
MATCH p=allShortestPaths(startnode-[:C0038969primrel*..4]->group)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Hi michael!! you're the savior! allShortestPaths made the query work really fast. I should have thought about it. :(
Thanks a lot!